# ./filename not running from subdir bin

Tags: bash, shell-script

My shebang is

```
#!bin/bash
```

I call the script with

```
./filename
```

This works with every other script I’ve written but this one.

If I run with `-x` I get some results but the script returns NO results on it’s own, just returns my command prompt, no errors ... ???

Comment: We can't help you debug a script you don't show us. Please [edit] your question and add i) your operating system, ii) the code of the script, iii) the expected result of running the script, iv) the actual result of running it, v) the results you get with `-x` (and also where you put this `-x`, do you mean `set -x`)?

Comment: Can you confirm that your script starts with `#!bin/bash` rather than with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: The "shebang" (`#!`) should normally be followed by an absolute and full path name (otherwise, it will try to use whatever the 'current directory' is at the time, which may not be what you expect)... In this case, `bin/bash` most likely should be `/bin/bash` or `/bin/env bash`.

Answer (score 1):

`#!bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash` Otherwise it will assume a directory `bin` in the current path and looks there for `bash`.